# Reading client certificate details with NGINX

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I want to read the client certificate passed by the user and extract the user information out of the certificate and pass add it as header to every subsequent request made by NGINX using reverse proxy (using proxy pass).

How can I read the client cert information on NGINX ?

Comment: Many parts of the client certificate are available in the [`$ssl_client_` variables](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#var_ssl_client_cert). To extract a specific aspect for a header, you can use a regular expression with a `map`.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thank you. Can you please point me to some samples. I am new to NGINX